# PHP not loading data with simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried the below code locally and it works fine,  when adding the same code into a wordpress page, the code it getting an unreachable warning.  The web service it is contacting is an external web service.

```
 $url = "http://xxxxxx.net/xxxx.asmx/GetWards";
 $wardsJSON = simplexml_load_file($url);
 $wardsArray = json_decode($wardsJSON, true);
```

The error is:
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.asmx/GetWards): failed to open stream: Network is unreachable in

I have also tried curl which also doesnt work but returns empty.

I have checked phpinfo() and allow_url_fopen is set to on.

The confusing part is that this works fine locally!!!!

Comment: That's a very weird URL structure, assuming the first set of "x" is indeed, followed by a "/".

Comment: corrected  url structure, added the tld to show its correct form

Comment: I may be a server problem and not of WordPress one. try this in a simple PHP file `$content = file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: I added a simple file at the root of the site (so ignoring wordpress)  comes up with  same error as simplexml_load_file error that its unreachable.  I believe this is going to be a server issue that my hosts will need to deal with.